# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']'

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error, tstringlist

Could someone please explain why I am recieving this error in the below code and what I can do to fix it, error is referring to : `echo "<tr><td>{$r['logID']}</td><td><a href='viewuser.php?u={$r['>{$r['username']}</a> [{$r['userID']}]</td><td>{$r['amount']}</td><td><a href='5050.php?chal={$r['>Challenge</a></td><td>";`

To put it into context here is the whole snippet.

```
<?php
include "globals.php";
$minbet=1;
$maxg=10;
echo "<big>50 / 50 Crystals Game</big>";
function add_game()
{
        global $ir,$t,$userid, $db, $minbet, $maxg;
        if(!isset($_POST['amt']))
        {
            echo "<big>Adding a game</big>
                <form action='5050.php?add=1' method='post'>
                Amount of crystals:<input type='text' name='amt' size=10 maxlength=10>
                <input type='submit' value='Add!'></form>
                ($maxg games max per user)
                <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";

        }
    else
        {
            $_POST['amt'] = abs((int) $_POST['amt']); 
            if($_POST['amt'] < $minbet)
                {
                    echo "The minimum bet is $minbet
                        <a href='5050.php?add=1'>Back</a>";exit;
                }
            $theckcount=$db->query("SELECT logID FROM tchance WHERE userID={$ir['userid']} and active=1");
            if($db->num_rows($theckcount) > ($maxg-1))
                {
                echo "There is a maximum of $maxg games per user.
                    <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";exit;
                }
            if($ir['crystals'] < $_POST['amt'])
                {
                echo "You cannot afford that amount.
                    <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";exit;
                }
            $db->query("UPDATE users SET crystals = crystals - {$_POST['amt']} WHERE userid = {$ir['userid']}");
            $ir['crystals']=$ir['crystals'] - $_POST['amt'];
            $db->query("INSERT INTO tchance VALUES ('', {$ir['userid']}, {$_POST['amt']}, 1)");
            echo "Your game has been set.  Good Luck.
                <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";
        }

}
function view_games()
{
        global $ir,$t,$userid, $db, $maxg;

        $q=$db->query("SELECT t.*, u.username FROM tchance t left join users u on u.userid = t.userID WHERE t.active = 1 ORDER BY t.logID ASC");

        echo "<a href='5050.php?add=1'>Add Game</a>

    Table of users awaiting a challenge

        <table class='table' width=50%><tr><th>Game ID</th><th>User</th><th>Amount</th><th>Challenge</th><th>Cancel</th></tr>";
        if($db->num_rows($q) < 1){echo "<tr><td colspan=5>There are currenly no challenges</td></tr>";}
        while($r=$db->fetch_row($q))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>{$r['logID']}</td><td><a href='viewuser.php?u={$r['>{$r['username']}</a> [{$r['userID']}]</td><td>{$r['amount']}</td><td><a href='5050.php?chal={$r['>Challenge</a></td><td>";
        if($ir['userid']==$r['userID']){echo "<a href='5050.php?cancel={$r['>Cancel</a>";}             
        echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        }
    function dogame()
        {
        global $ir,$t,$userid, $db;
        $_GET['chal'] = abs((int) $_GET['chal']);
        $q=$db->query("SELECT t.*, u.username from tchance t LEFT JOIN users u ON t.userID = u.userid Where t.logID={$_GET['chal']} AND t.active = 1 LIMIT 1");
        if($db->num_rows($q) > 0)
        {
            $r=$db->fetch_row($q);
            if($ir['crystals'] < $r['amount'])
                {
                    echo "You cannot afford the challenge amount.
                    <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";exit;
                }
                if($ir['userid'] == $r['userID'])
                {
                    echo "You cannot accept your own challenge.
                    <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";exit;
                }
                if(rand(1,2) == 1)
                {
                    $winner=$r['userID']; $loser=$ir['userid'];
                    $winnername=$r['username'];
                    $losername=$ir['username'];
                    $tstring="Sorry, you Lost. Better luck next time.
                    <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";
                    $db->query("UPDATE users SET crystals = crystals - {$r['amount']} WHERE userid={$ir['userid']}");
                    $db->query("UPDATE users SET crystals = crystals + ({$r['amount']} * 2) WHERE userid={$r['userID']}");
                }
                else
                {
                    $winner=$ir['userid']; $loser=$r['userID'];
                    $winnername=$ir['username'];
                    $losername=$r['username'];
                    $tstring="You Won! Congratulations! You Won {$r['amount']} crystals. 
                    <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";
                    $db->query("UPDATE users SET crystals = crystals + {$r['amount']} WHERE userid={$ir['userid']}");
                }
                event_add($winner, "The game of {$r['amount']} crystals challenged by <a href='viewuser.php?u={$r['>{$r['username']}</a> was won by <a href='viewuser.php?u={$winner}'>{$winnername}</a>.", $t);
                event_add($loser, "The game of {$r['amount']} crystals challenged by <a href='viewuser.php?u={$r['>{$r['username']}</a> was won by <a href='viewuser.php?u={$winner}'>{$winnername}</a>.", $t);
                $db->query("UPDATE tchance SET active = 0 WHERE logID={$_GET['chal']}");
                echo $tstring;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "This game has either been cancelled or someone played before you got the 5050.
            <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>"; exit;
        }
    }


function cancel()
{
    global $ir,$t,$userid, $db;
    $_GET['cancel'] = abs((int) $_GET['cancel']);
    $q=$db->query("SELECT * from tchance where logID={$_GET['cancel']} AND active = 1");
    if($db->num_rows($q) > 0)
    {
        $r=$db->fetch_row($q);
        $db->query("UPDATE users SET crystals = crystals + {$r['amount']} WHERE userid = {$ir['userid']}");
        $ir['crystals']=$ir['crystals'] + $r['amount'];
        $db->query("UPDATE tchance SET active = -1 WHERE logID = {$_GET['cancel']}");
        echo "The game has been cancelled, and your crystals has been returned.
        <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";
    }
        else
    {
        echo "This game has already been canceled, does not exist, or someone already played.
        <a href='5050.php'>Back</a>";
    }
 
}

if(isset($_GET['cancel'])){cancel();}
elseif(isset($_GET['chal'])){dogame();}
elseif(isset($_GET['add'])){add_game();}
else{view_games();}

?>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me and teach me.

Comment: I believe i've done as you both say, but i get this: http://codepad.org/YDD25GPW

Comment: This is getting ridiculous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<tr><td>{$r['logID']}</td><td><a href='viewuser.php?u={$r['>{$r['username']}</a> [{$r['userID']}]</td><td>{$r['amount']}</td><td><a href='5050.php?chal={$r['>Challenge</a></td><td>";
```

You have "$r[" in the middle of double quotes. Escape it with a slash and you'll be better off (PHP is trying to evaluate your variable). You probably don't mean to have $r, but just r

```
    echo "<tr><td>{$r['logID']}</td><td><a href='viewuser.php?u={\$r['>{$r['username']}</a> [{$r['userID']}]</td><td>{$r['amount']}</td><td><a href='5050.php?chal={$r['>Challenge</a></td><td>";
```

I personally think your syntax is confusing, I'd rather use "." to concatenate the strings and variables:

```
echo ' <tr><td>'
         .   $r['logID']
         . '</td><td>'
         .  '<a href="viewuser.php?u=r[' . $r['username'] .']">'.$r['username'].'</a>'
         .  '['.$r['userID'].']</td><td>'
         .  $r['amount'] . '</td><td>'
         . '<a href="5050.php?chal=r">Challenge</a></td><td>';
```

Comment: thanks chwagssd, I did that but now i receive an unexpected tstring where it is expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the array:
`?chal={$r['>Challenge</a></td><td>`

Comment: I believe i have closed it now, still receive the same error though :( http://codepad.org/YDD25GPW

Answer (score 0):

You also have many unescaped double-quotes in your echo, which is causing yet another error. See if you can find them! It's good practice.

I also recommend using single-quotes when you're excessively using double quotes, and vice versa.